# multiply radio button value and display result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've looked up several examples however to no avail, I need someone to help me format the javascript function for code below. I simply want to select a radio option, and multiply the value by 1.06 and then display the results.

```
<form name="price">
<p><input type="radio" name=arrangement_size value="50" style="height: 30px; width: 30px" checked="checked">option 1</p>
<p><input type="radio" name=arrangement_size value="75" style="height: 30px; width: 30px">option 2</p>
<p><input type="radio" name=arrangement_size value="125" style="height: 30px; width: 30px">option 3</p>
</form>

<input type="text" name="totalSum" id="totalSum" value="" size="2" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: ***I need someone to help me format the JavaScript*** Where is JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$('#totalsum').val($('#price input[name="arrangement_size"]:checked').val() * 1.06);
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS:

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2MUX6/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  var rads = document.getElementsByName("arrangement_size");
  for (var i=0;i<rads.length;i++) {
    rads[i].onclick=function() {
      document.getElementsByName("totalSum")[0].value=(this.value*1.06).toFixed(2);
    }
    if (rads[i].checked) rads[i].click(); // set the initial value
  }
}
```

jQuery

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jXWQr/)

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name="arrangement_size"]').on("click",function() {
    $("#totalSum").val((this.value*1.06).toFixed(2));
  });
  $('input[name="arrangement_size"]:checked').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
parseInt($('input[type=radio]:checked').val())*1.06
```